# Setting a default integer variable in PHP

Tags: php

In Java when I declare a variable  int A; by default it assigns 0 to the variable A. But in PHP if I declare a variable as $A the default value of it sets as null. Instead of assigning it as $A=0; are there any ways available to set a default value as 0 for variable $A, as I did in Java?

Comment: PHP does not use variable types, so you will have to do $A=0 when you declare $A

Comment: @Deep PHP *has* types, but they're inferred instead of declared.

Comment: @Hiru Don't try to port habits from other languages to PHP. PHP isn't Java and Java isn't PHP. Nobody uses "implicit type default values" in PHP the way you are trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set its type. Since you don't wana initialize to 0, setting type to integer will do that for you.

```
<?php

settype($foo, "integer"); 

echo $foo;

?>
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/Yeva0BFq)**

Comment: +1 This somewhat disproves my point, but IMO is basically casting in another syntax and too verbose to be actually useful. :)

Comment: This basically does `$foo = (int)null`. If `$foo` already existed before, who knows what you're going to get?

Comment: Thank you for replying. This explains what I need. Isn't this a precise  way of doing it. I'm really sorry if Im asking a stupid question. Im totally new to PHP.... :)

Comment: @Hiru But it's exactly the same as `$foo = 0;` except more verbose and error-prone, so why would you want to use it?

Comment: Juhana and Deceze you are right, I agree. But then given the fact that this question did not have much practical significance, I considered it was only a challenge they were underdoing and hence gave one possible solution. It isn't the best way to go about it.

Comment: Right, nothing wrong with the answer. It just seems like OP is treating PHP as a strongly typed language, so it's worth noting that this won't actually enforce `$foo` as an integer type (i.e. `settype($foo, "integer"); $foo = "bar";` won't even throw a warning).

Answer (score 4):

Since you do not explicitly declare variables to be of a certain type, but PHP does type inference instead, there's no way to make an integer without assigning an integer value. In Java you can make a default value by declaring the type of a variable, in PHP you declare the type of a variable by assigning a value of that type to it. There may be several ways how to get an integer value of `0`, but none is as straight forward as using a literal `0`.

Answer (score 3):

you can do like this, following will help you

```
echo (int)$A;
```

Comment: This is basically just producing an integer value, it's not setting the type of the variable.

Comment: But it gives an error like this. Can't I avoid it?
Notice: Undefined variable: count in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHIS2\CreateTheForm.php on line 5

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't by default make a variable integer or string, if you want to set default value, then simply write`$myvariable = 0;` and this will assign and make variable an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `php` `settype` which set the type of a variable

```
<?php

settype($var,'integer');
echo $var;

?>
```

Refer `php` [settype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php)